# java.lang.InterruptedException while running Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, interrupted-exception

I was running jasper reports in Java to generate report and I used virtualizer to handle huge data. However, after almost 3 hours of running suddenly java.lang.InterruptedException was thrown. It was caught by my program and here's the stack trace. What I know is that this exception is thrown only when some other process interrupts a sleeping or idle process. In my case, what other process could have interrupted this?

Below is the console output:

```
    INFO: Filename:filename.pdf
    08 8, 11 1:06:57 PM com.main.HugeReportGeneratorDriver generateSubReport
    INFO: [INFO] Output File: filename.pdf
    08 8, 11 3:33:43 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner suspend
    SEVERE: Fill 8072489: exception
    java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.suspend(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:185)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.suspendSubreportRunner(JRBaseFiller.java:2095)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.addPage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1836)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1916)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1945)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2048)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:757)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:289)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:131)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:938)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:608)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I suspect the problem lies in jasper report, am I correct? Is there any way I can handle this is my program?

Thanks a lot!

-Brevis Iunius

Comment: Does your report run well with less amounts of data?

Comment: Thank you Markus. Yes, it does! Have you encountered this error?